# Hide pdf toolbar with pdfjs with laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, laravel-5, pdf.js

Please I need to be guided on how to remove the pdf toolbar from a pdf document I dynamically display on a page on my website to discourage printing and downloading of the document from the website.

This is the toolbar[image]

On web.php route page, I have the following route

```
Route::get('showresource/{id}','ResourceController@show');
```

Which returns the file and is then displayed in the following blade page

```
    <object data="{{url('showresource/'.$current_lesson->resource_file)}}" type="{{$mime_type}}" height="600px" width="100%" id="resource-pdf" style=""></object>
```

I have added the following javascript to the page to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#resource-pdf').contents().find('#toolbar').css('display','none');
   });
```

This does not seem to be working.

I have also tried to use pdfjs but I don't know how to apply it to a laravel 5 project. I look forward to any support to solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case (chrome-based web browser) this bar is a `<viewer-pdf-toolbar>` HTML tag. If you add to your css file or between `<style>` tag this code

```
viewer-pdf-toolbar {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The bar will disappear. Don't do this by inline method because this tag is often overwritten by web browser. My way is tested and works perfect.

Comment: how widely is this supported between browsers?

Comment: This way will work on all browsers but I'm not sure if all browsers use ```<viewer-pdf-toolbar>``` tag. I don't have currently any way to check this on the other browser than chrome-based.